# how to stop growing width of window when child sizers width increased in wx.Dialog in wxpython

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I am very new to wxpython and wxwidgets.I have the code for wx.Dialog like below.

```
def __init__(self, parent, Name, Platform):
    wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, -1, 'Launch Dialog', size=(-1,-1), pos=(-1,-1))
     ###some code 
    self.createSizers()
    self.Fit() 

def createSizers()
    self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    SelectionSizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.staticBoxTestSelection, wx.VERTICAL)
    self.horzDetailsSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) 
    self.DetailsSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    ### add func here

    self.ListingSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    ### add func here

     # Horizontal Splitter
    self.horzDetailsSizer.Add(self.ListingSizer, 3, wx.EXPAND)
    self.horzDetailsSizer.AddSpacer(5)
    self.horzDetailsSizer.Add(self.DetailsSizer, 2, wx.EXPAND)

    # Add subsizers to main
    SelectionSizer.Add(self.horzDetailsSizer, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

    self.mainSizer.Add(SelectionSizer, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 5)

     ### Initialize mainSize
    self.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
```

Here the problem is when the statictextctrl sizers or listctrl sizers of `self.DetailsSizer` increase width of whole window size and also subsizers width is increasing on right side of window.

I wish to fix the dialog box size and the subsizers should adjust within the window size.That is if one subsizer width is increased, adjacent subsizer should adjust with the space..

Is there any way to do that? Please help me to get rid of this issue.

**EDIT**:

This is not about user resizing the dialog window..it is about the width of dialog box dynamically growing horizontally.

For ex. in my dialog box I have 2 box sizers named as listing and details adjacent to each other in the window of default size(-1,-1).

In details box I am displaying 'name' dynamically which is related to selected option from listing sizer..So the length of 'name' will change every time..If the length is more and the string is a single word the width of details sizer is increased horizontally so that listing sizer increased.So main sizer of window increased like below.

I do not want this growing and again coming to normal window.The window size should always fix and in case of 'name' length increased in details sizer ,the listing sizer should shrink and adjust with the detail sizer.

Normal Dialog box:

[image]

Dynamically width increased:

[image]

Desired output to be:

[image]

Comment: it's not clear what do you expect. Do you want the dialog to have a fixed size so the user will not be able to resize it? Or the user should be able to resize it but the space on the right should stay the same? Please clarify.

Comment: No,it is not actually about user rezing the window..It is dynamically resizing the window horizontally when for ex. text size(length of string)  increases or decreases in any one of subsizers will change the width(horizontal sizer) of window  as well as subsizer. widow's width should be fixed always even the sub sizers width increased so that it should manage the space with other subsizers.I have no idea of how to do it in wxDialog

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to add a sizer without proportion. Look at this code

```
# Horizontal Splitter
self.horzDetailsSizer.Add(self.ListingSizer, 3, wx.EXPAND) # This Line need to be changed
self.horzDetailsSizer.AddSpacer(5)
self.horzDetailsSizer.Add(self.DetailsSizer, 2, wx.EXPAND)
```

When you put the proportion 0, the children will not grow on x axis, only in y axis (Because the `wx.EXPAND` is used). Try to change like code bellow

```
self.horzDetailsSizer.Add(self.ListingSizer, 0, wx.EXPAND)
```

This blog (http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/11/06/wxpython-101-using-frame-styles) have an explanation to wx Flags. To make a Dialog without resize try to put:

```
class TestDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self,parent)
        dialogStyle = wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE& ~ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.RESIZE_BOX | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX)
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, -1, style=dialogStyle)
```

Comment: this is works fine..but what can I do for horizontal scrollbar in ListingSizer if detailSizers content increased?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but you're calling `Fit()` so that your dialog width is set to whatever best fits its contents. If you don't want this to happen, as I interpreted your question, just don't call `Fit()`. Of course, this may result in the dialog being too narrow to show everything inside it, which is why calling `Fit()` usually is a good idea, but it's your choice whether to do it or not.

Comment: I have tried to remove Fit() but still it is growing horizontally :-(

Comment: `wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, -1, 'Launch Dialog', size=(-1,-1), pos=(-1,-1))`   here I change the size to (870,700) but it remains the same

Comment: @Nithya, as Vadim, I also didn't understand the question. Are you trying to prevent the user of resizing the dialog? If not, can you produce the screenshot of what is initial, what is happening right now and what do you expect to see? Thx.

Comment: Dialogs really don't just grow on their own. If you don't call `Fit()`, the dialog size should be whatever you explicitly set for it or some default (but fixed) size used by default.

Comment: The `Fit()` has been removed but no change on the behavior and also I could not set size.