# wxPython-size of wxdialog is not changing

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

In my project, statement for Wxdialog is 
`wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, 'Launch dialog', size=(-1,-1), pos=(-1,-1))`

I have tried to increase the dialog box size by setting the size from `size=(-1,-1)` to `size=(800,750)`

But nothing has changed..Is there any reason behind this.Please help me to solve this.

Comment: The wx.Dialog is being shown?

Comment: ya dialog is opening..but with default size of parent i guess.

Comment: try to put self.SetSize((sizex,sizey)) at the end of init function. If dont work try to call dialog.SetSize after creation of instance

Comment: @GabrielAlberto,,Thanks for the response.I have tried both ways.when opening dialog box the given size is coming.But after selecting anything  (for ex: I have ListBox in dialog window) it again goes to normal size.

Comment: Also My dialog window growing and shrinking dynamically with content.I wish to fit this.If content is more, the sizers  should adjust within the dialog window.I have two adjacent box sizers.if content in one sizer increases,other sizer should shrink and scroll for its content.can we do this? For ref:[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112551/how-to-stop-growing-width-of-window-when-child-sizers-width-increased-in-wx-dial

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.
Here is a working dialog from a live project

```
class Rem_mess(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self,parent,ddate,dtext,dtype):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, dtype, size= (320,240), pos=(1000,10))
        font = wx.SystemSettings_GetFont(wx.SYS_SYSTEM_FONT)
        font.SetPointSize(9)
        self.SetWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
        self.snooze_list = ['Snooze for','5 Mins','15 Mins','30 Mins','1 Hour','1 Day','1 Week','No Snooze']
        self.snooze_mins = [0,5,15,30,60,1440,10080,0]
        time_panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        time_panel.SetFont(font)

        label_date = wx.StaticText(time_panel, wx.ID_ANY, (ddate))
        label_text = wx.TextCtrl(time_panel, wx.ID_ANY, style= wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY, size=(300,110))
        self.snooze = wx.Choice(time_panel, wx.ID_ANY, choices=self.snooze_list,size=(200,28))
        self.quit_button = wx.Button(time_panel, label="&Close", size=(70,30))
        time_panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(201, 196, 255))
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(hgap=2,vgap=2)
        sizer.Add(label_date, pos=(0,1), flag = wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(label_text, pos=(1,1), flag = wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.snooze, pos=(2,1), flag = wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.quit_button,pos=(4,1), flag =wx.ALL|wx.CENTER)
        time_panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.quit_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnQuit)
        label_text.SetValue(dtext)

    def OnQuit(self, event):
        self.Close()

    def GetSelection(self):
        idx = self.snooze.GetSelection()
        return self.snooze_mins[idx]

    def GetSelectionString(self):
        return self.snooze.GetString(self.snooze.GetSelection())
```

And it is called like this:

```
    res = Rem_mess(parent=None, ddate=d_date,dtext=d_text,dtype="Reminder")
    if res.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        snooze_res = res.GetSelection()
    res.Destroy()
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution..This is not working for my case.Parent should not be 'None' for my dialog.If I make it None ,Attribute error is coming.

Comment: Without a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example we're dancing in the dark. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi please see this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112551/how-to-stop-growing-width-of-window-when-child-sizers-width-increased-in-wx-dial ]..This is also posted by me with the above problem also.

Comment: Sadly, that is neither minimal nor complete nor verifiable.